# Reported a VP for harassment. He resigned during the investigation. What can I do

Tags: human-resources, harassment, california

The VP asked me very inappropriate questions during office hours while no one was around and I said 'no' multiple times. Did more investigation on my own to see if anyone else was effected by him and uncovered a lot. Made a report to HR and the VP was suspended during the investigation. The VP resigned the next day, but official email was not sent out yet. I discovered he might be a pathological liar.  What can I do from here so this won't happen again at other companies they might end up at???

Comment: That sorted out what you actually meant...

Comment: You've already got good answers below here. But let me add: You've solved the problem already. Congratulations. Let it go now. He has done wrong and has been punished. Enough is enough. Being a liar (in most countries at least) is not itself a reason for legal action. Defamation, on the other hand, is! So don't commit an offense yourself because you are assuming someone else will do wrong in the future.

Answer (score 7):

First: a big thank you for taking action and it's good to see that companies can learn, take the right decisions and remove such persons if honest people give feedback risking their career. You already made the world a slightly better place, and I am not sure that you actually have an obligation to do more.

Since you asked about the possibilities my answers below.

> What can I do from here so this won't happen again at other companies
>   they might end up at???

- Nothing without endangering your career - if there is a move against him it should not come from the person where your company knows (since you reported him) about.
- The logics here is: Your company acted as far as I understood appropriately (unless former VPs behaviors crossed the line to criminal behavior) and swiftly - unless the issue for you wasn't addressed fully by this, it's not yours to take that public, since it may pose a legal risk to the company.
- Given the facts I would assume it's not likely that anybody from the current company would give him a reference - together with the facts future employers see in the CV this speaks volumes
- If he actually gets a good reference, then it's your word against the person giving the reference.
- The only way would be if you actually know for sure that there are so many victims of his behavior that when whistle blowing you will be a needle in a stack of needles
- If you actually uncovered criminal behavior, the person affected by the criminal behavior need to take this where she/he sees it fit - maybe discuss this in private with the corresponding person. Maybe he/she actually doesn't want to follow this up further.

Answer (score 0):

You have done your thing. This VP now has a very sudden resignation on his CV. There's hope that he is not incorrigible and learns from his mistakes.

Especially as two sudden resignations are a very, very red flag. And because the next HR will know which company he resigned from very suddenly and can make careful enquiries if needed. If there are new claims of harassment then HR of the new company surely can add two and two together and will make enquiries.

The answer (of your own HR) would probably be something like "you will understand that we cannot comment on individual cases, but it has happened in the past that employees resigned because of harrassment charges" or whatever is legally safe to say.